# Sqlite match specific characters before wildcard

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

In transitioning from MS Access to Sqlite, I have a minor problem
The following `[,. ]%` works well in MS Access for matching characters comma, period and space after a word but not in Sqlite.

For example for the dictionary phrases "`aaa, bbb ccc`" and "`aaa, bbbbbb ccc`" if the user types "`aaa bbb`", it becomes "`aaa[,. ]%bbb`" and then it goes into a `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text LIKE ?`. This doesn't work in Sqlite but it did in MS Access. Also I want it only to select the first dictionary phrase, not the second.

So, my question is how do I match a set of characters in Sqlite?

edit: I am not able to use regex's so I would like a solution without regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't and you need to use `REGEXP`.

The best thing that I can figure is something like this:

```
select *
from t
where replace(replace(txt, ',', ''), '.', '') like 'aaa bbb%';
```

That will not cover `aaa,bbbb` or `aaa  bbbb`.

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL, LIKE does not have character classes.

In SQLite, you can use [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) instead:

```
... WHERE text GLOB 'aaa[,. ]*bbb'
```

(GLOB is case sensitive.)